# Is using a timestamp field with concat(to_date) the most efficient way to query previous day in Impala?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, impala, impyla

I am querying data from HDFS using Impala in a python script using the python library Impyla.  The specific data is proxy data and there is tons of it.  I have a script that runs daily to pull the previous day and runs statistics.  Currently I am using the `devicereceipttime` field for this query which is stored as a timestamp.

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.util import as_pandas
import pandas as pd

#Pull desired features from the proxy_realtime_p table
cursor.execute('select request, count(*) as count \
from default.proxy_realtime_p \
where devicereceipttime BETWEEN concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), " 00:00:00") and concat(to_date(now() - interval 1 days), " 23:59:59") \
group by request \
order by count desc')
```

This query takes a little bit and would like to speed this up if possible.  From the given fields below is my query the most efficient?

```
devicereceipttime (timestamp)
year (int)
month (int)
day (int)
hour (int)
minute (int)
seconds (int)
```